# Change an image every minute using the computer's clock to time the changes

Tags: javascript, image, clock, minute

I want to change an image every minute. When the computer's clock moves from 8:50 to 8:51 then to 8:52 all the way back to 8:49 I want my picture to change from 0001.jpg to 0002.jpg to 0003.jpg all the way to 1440.jpg.

Since I am going to be using the computer's clock, I am interested in using JavaScript. I am also just starting out, so full code (which would be awesome!) is probably not what I need. Instead, I am looking for a place to start and maybe a direction to go. Any resources online that you know of would also be helpful

Comment: I would prefer (as a end-user) that the image changes by the time of the day and not by minute, like, morning, lunch, afternoon, night... every minute would be a little overkill don't you think?

Comment: @balexandre, not an overkill if your images display clock :)

@Travis, please, for the sake of end-users and their poor browsers, consider using [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) instead of 1400 images.

Comment: @mkilmanas, it's for my wife, gonna make a clock of our pictures.

Comment: @everyone who has answered so far: HUGE THANK YOU! I have a lot to look over.

Comment: @Travis in this site we don't say **Thank you** in words, just **upvote** the answer and set one of the answers as the correct one.

Comment: @balexandre, life doesn't have to be too square, a thank you is fine

Comment: @mkilmanas, a 1400 images sprite, especially jpeg, is probably few megabytes to load before starting. Not sure it is the right approach in that case. Preloading few of them in advance would be probably helpful.

Comment: @Mic, read the Faq's that's what's there!

Answer (score 2):

compute how many seconds until the next minute starts, then using `setTimeout` begin rotating the pictures. Use `setInterval` to do so every 60000 milliseconds.

```
var seconds = 60 - new Date().getSeconds();


setTimeout(function(){

    console.log('start');

    setInterval(function(){

        console.log ('iterate over pictures here');

    }, 1000 * 60);

}, seconds * 1000);
```

You can read more about both functions [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to study up on [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval).

The code would look something like this:

```
var counter = 1,
lastUpdate = (new Date()).getTime(),
img = document.getElementById('image'); // Assuming your HTML has an img tag
                                        // with an id of "image"
// This function just pads your number with 0s
function pad(num) {
    var padding = '',
    i = 4 - num.toString().length;
    while (i > 0) {
        padding += '0';
        i -= 1;
    }
    return padding + num;
}    

// This function is what actually does the updating
function update() {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (lastUpdate + 1000 <= now) {
        lastUpdate = now;
    img.src = pad(counter) + '.jpg'; // change the image
    counter += 1; // increment the counter

    if (counter > 1440) { // reset to 1 if we get to our last image
        counter = 1;
    }
    }
}

// Run update every 10th of a second
setInterval(update, 100);
```

The Mozilla Developer Center site has lots of great [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) references.  I would also suggest learning to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), it will help a lot in avoiding stupid syntax errors that will cause headaches. I would suggest reading Douglas Crockford's book *JavaSript: The Good Parts* and Stoyan Stefanov's *Object-Oriented JavaScript* they are both excellent books to learn JavaScript from.

Answer (score 1):

Place the code below in the BODY of a page:

```
<img />
<script>
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        i = 0,
        //get the node of the image to change
        img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0]; 

    setInterval(function(){
        //what time is now
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if(now - start > 60000){
            //initialize the counter
            start = now;
            //overlay with 0's -> substr(-4)
            //rotate on 1440 with a modulo -> i++ % 1440
            img.src = ('000' + (i++ % 1440 + 1)).substr(-4)  + '.jpg';
        }
    }, 10000); //check every 10 sec
</script>
```

If you start with Javascript a good reference is [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript)

Comment: Could you explane the <img /> tag to me please?

Comment: It is the placeholder of the picture. To use it then in `javascript` you can get it with `document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0]` and then change its source url with `img.src = ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this tied to the computer clock. Use the `setInterval` with a delay less than a second (<1000) and check the actual time with `Date()`. This way you can make your changes according to the clock.